# AngularJS and XML, how to render it?

Tags: javascript, xml, angularjs

I am working along DB guys, they are sending me the data thru XML, and depending the kind of element they specify is what I need to display in the view.

The code you will see is a dynamic table

```
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="column in cols">
              <span>{{column}}</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
            <td ng-repeat="column in cols"
                ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0">
              <span ng-if="!isXX">{{row[column]}}</span>
              <button ng-if="isXX" class="btn btn-xs btn-blue"
                      ng-click="fillOpen()">
                  {{column.substring(3).replace('_', ' ')}}
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

and here is what I have in the controller

```
    ReportsFactory.pendingBets(reportParam).then(function(data) {
      if (data.length) {
        gridInfo = _.forEach(data, function(item) {return item;});
        $scope.rows = gridInfo;
        $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
      }
    }
```

as you can see here I have this `ng-init`

`ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0"` where I am telling the app, if the property I am receiving comes with `XX` at the index, then display a button `<button ng-if="isXX" ng-click="fillOpen()">...</button>` but so far, I have some more props coming with `XX` at the beginning, so I need to do it more dynamic.

This is how my view looks so far

[image]

what I need to know, is how to read that XML, this is the XML printed in the Nodejs terminal

```
[{ BET: 57635034,
  CUSTOMER: 181645,
  SPORT: 'NFL',
  'XX_FILL OPEN': '<element><element_type>WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON</element_type><element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call><element_content/></element>',
  XX_VIEW: '<element><element_type>BASIC_DROPDOWN</element_type><element_call>callThisFunction()</element_call><element_content><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></element_content></element>',
  XX_CANCEL: '<element><element_type>BASIC_CHECKBOX</element_type><element_call/><element_content>1</element_content></element>'
}]
```

so, the first says

```
'XX_FILL OPEN': '<element><element_type>WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON</element_type><element_call>fillOpen(57635034)</element_call><element_content/></element>'
```

`WAGER_ACTION_BUTTON` should be a button

the second one says

`BASIC_DROPDOWN` that should be a dropdown and so on, so, how should I do in order to display the proper HTML element depending on what the XML says ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Parse it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: @azium ummm, but actually I have all that done already, what I need to know is how to render it in the DOM, can you provide me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly you want to dynamically render the xml or html content to your view... I assume that element and element type are directive you have or something.

use
[ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

e.g:

```
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 m-r-offset-8 p-t-offset-2 font-l-16">
        <span mathjax-bind ng-bind-html="question.question.body"></span>
    </div>
```

or you might need to use the trustAsHtml function

```
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 m-r-offset-8 p-t-offset-2 font-l-16">
        <span mathjax-bind ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(question.question.body)"></span>
    </div>

$scope.trustAsHtml = function (val) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
};
```

this will take your string xml (html) code and render it...
you could always build a personalize directive and use $compile as well like:

```
app.directive('ngHtmlCompile',function ($compile) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.$watch(
            function(scope) {
               // watch the 'compile' expression for changes
              return scope.$eval(attrs.ngHtmlCompile);
            },
            function(value) {
              // when the 'compile' expression changes
              // assign it into the current DOM
              element.html(value);

              // compile the new DOM and link it to the current
              // scope.
              // NOTE: we only compile .childNodes so that
              // we don't get into infinite loop compiling ourselves
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            }
        );
    };
});
```

and in the code just call the ng-html-compile... no need for $sce

Comment: instead of calling {{row...}} or wherever you call your html data use <span ng-bind-html="trustAsHtml(row...)"> 
or use the ng-html-compile just without the trustAsHtml like <span ng-html-compile="row...">

Comment: OK, but how this method is going to know that this `XX_CANCEL: '<element><element_type>BASIC_CHECKBOX</element_type><element_call/><element_content>1</element_content></element>'` should be a checkbox ? there is something I don't get.

Comment: it doesnt... you need to handle the directives yourself... if will just render the html code... if the <element-type> is not a directive then you need to build a directive to generate the html elements...what I showed you relayed on the assumption that those directives already exist

Comment: actually this is now good, because I am just displaying text, and not a dropdown or buttons

Comment: so if you just want to show the text... my solution is what you need.... if you need to render an element then you need to create directives to read the html attribute and generate the elements for you :)

Comment: OK, I'll figure it out then. Thanks

Comment: sure, all you need to do is pass to the directive element type and classes or whatever and then with a switch set an html element in a var and finally use $compile... also dont forget to transclude... or pass element messsage